# Распаковка и запуск exe из ресурсов программы

Tags: c#, exe, ресурсы, .net

Здравствуйте.
У меня имеется уже собраная программа на c# (моя же), и я бы хотел что бы это программа извлекалась куда-нибудь например в Temp, потом запускалась из программы, и после того как программа поработает с этим файлом она удаляла его из Temp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Создаем или очищаем папку, куда будем распаковывать файл из ресурсов.
2. Копируем туда свой исполняемый файл.

   ```
   File.WriteAllBytes("путь_**.exe", Properties.Resources.your_file);
   ```
3. Запускаем свой исполняемый файл и ждем завершения (лучше не в основном потоке).

   ```
   Process p = new Process();
   p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("путь_**.exe");
   p.Start();
   p.WaitForExit();
   ```
4. Удаляем файл и папку. File.Delete("имя"), Directory.Delete("имя") etc...
5. ?????
6. PROFIT

**Обновление**

Ну например "Temp" - это будет папка Temp в папке, где находится исполняемый файл. Т.е. так мы задаем относительный(относительно исполняемого файла) путь к файлу. Загуглите "абсолютные и относительные пути".

Answer (score -2):

Попробуйте не использовать встроенные "Resources", с этим всем возникают некоторые проблемы. Гораздо проще организовать собственный деплой, и это не сложно.

Предположим, у вас есть "cmd.exe", который вы хотите запихать внутрь основного исполняемого файла, и этот "cmd.exe" хотите запустить как отдельный процесс. Делается это следующим образом.

```
namespace YourAssemblyNamespace
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // Добавьте "cmd.exe" в ваш проект
            // Add -> Existing item -> ваш "cmd.exe"
            // Добавляйте "cmd.exe" не как ресурс, а прямиком в корень проекта
            // Установите compile-property для "cmd.exe" как "Embedded"

            // Создайте поток и читайте ресурс "cmd.exe" в поток
            using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetManifestResourceStream("YourAssemblyNamespace.cmd.exe"))
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
            {
                // Поток в байты
                byte[] bytes = reader.ReadBytes((int)reader.BaseStream.Length);
                // ..создайте Temp где нужно
                // ..и запишите байты в файл
                File.WriteAllBytes(@"Temp\cmd.exe", bytes);
            }

            // Процесс для "cmd.exe"
            // Как создаётся и запускается процесс - не важно, далее псевдокод
            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            using (var p = new Process())
            {
                p.StartInfo = psi;
                p.Start();
            }

            //while (true) { }

            Console.ReadLine();

            // Удалите "cmd.exe"
            File.Delete(@"Temp\cmd.exe");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151771/discussion-on-answer-by-interceptortsk----exe---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.