# C# Запуск консольного приложения из папки Resourcer

Tags: c#

Есть консольное приложение

```
        private void cmd()
    {
        Process p = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = с:\cmd\cmd.exe,                
            Arguments = arguments,
            UseShellExecute = false, // false для скрытия
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
        });

        p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; // запускать приложение в фоновом режиме (Hidden)
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
        p.BeginErrorReadLine();
        p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(TSharkOutputHandler);
        p.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(TSharkOutputHandler);           
    }
```

Хочу чтобы это приложение было внутри исполняемого файла.
Для этого через Resources.resx добавил приложение в проект.
Появилась папка "Resources" и запускаемое приложение внутри.

Как мне сейчас обратиться к исполняемому файлу?

Comment: Winforms?......

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/353033/220553

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделал